# Need explanation of Membership operator in

Tags: python, operators, membership

```
y = {3:'a',4:'b'} 

print(3 in y)  # True
print("b" in y)  # False
```

Using membership operator `in`
why `print("b" in y)` result is `False`?

Comment: It's checking the dictionary keys, not the values.

Comment: Use `"b" in y.values()` to search the values.

Answer (score 1):

if the **y** is dictionary, the **in** operator checks the keys (3 and 4 in your case) of the dict. If you want to check that the dict contains value **"b"**, try following:

```py
y = {3:'a',4:'b'} 
print('b' in y.values())
```

The result will be **True** in this case.